# Getting the individual field from response ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a little trial and error react practice on a real-time COVID 19 API data from https://covid19.mathdro.id/api

So far I am able to get the response from console.log(response) but as much as I tried to get the confirmed value to display on a div tag, it gives me an error. How do I get the individual fields like recovered, confirmed, death and lastUpdate from the response? Thanks and here is the code:

```
   App.js

import React, { useState, useEffect }  from 'react';

import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:4000";

export const App = () => {
  const [response,setResponse] = useState("");


  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on("CovidAPI", data => {setResponse(data);
    });
  }, []);

           return (
              <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
               <div>{console.log(response)}</div>
            </div>
          )
        }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the response contains data as this : https://covid19.mathdro.id/api

Then you can do it like this :

```
const [response,setResponse] = useState(null); // <-- make it null for easy validate data


<div>
   {response && response.confirmed.value} // <-- check && display
</div>
```

---

You can run the below code snippet and review, Hope this will clear your doubts :

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

  const [response,setresponse] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api').then(resp => {
         setresponse(resp.data)
      })
  },[]);

  return (
    response ? 
    <div>
      Confirmed : {response.confirmed.value} <br/>
      Recovered : {response.recovered.value} <br/>
      Deaths : {response.deaths.value} <br/>
    </div> :
    <div> Loading ... </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `response` is valid object with required properties you can display as

```
return (
        <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
           <div>Recovered: {response.recovered}</div>
        </div>
       )
```